# Change quick search ACL from "Access CiviCRM" to "Edit all Contacts"

Tags: acl, civicrm-home

CiviCRM 4.6 - client requirements - how to go about changing which ACL the Menu (including Quick Search) is tied to?

The Menu appears to be tied to Access CiviCRM - but we'd like to change this to "Edit all Contacts".

Ideally, we'd just like to hide the Quick Search - "Access CiviCRM" appears to grant all access to contacts, even if "view" and "edit" all contacts is not expressly assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Time for a custom extension! I'd 
hook_civicrm_navigationMenu this bad boy - just hiding it in the JS won't help you from a security perspective.